# Parse youtube feed output

Tags: parsing, xml-parsing

Hello I am having a problem retrieving a value from this [link](https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VdbUBcOCU_A).
So far I've been using this line of code.

```
$str = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VdbUBcOCU_A";
$blow =(explode("'",$str));

            print_r($blow);
```

And echoes out "Array" would appreciate any help how to retrieve a value from the link. Thanks.

Comment: What programming language do you use? What do you want to achive?

Comment: Looks like PHP to me.

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct, you are using PHP?

Suggest you use Google PHP client library at https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php

For your case, see https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php#Video_Entry_Contents

```
$videoEntry = $yt->getVideoEntry('VdbUBcOCU_A');
printVideoEntry($videoEntry);

function printVideoEntry($videoEntry) 
{
  echo 'Video: ' . $videoEntry->getVideoTitle() . "\n";
  echo 'Video ID: ' . $videoEntry->getVideoId() . "\n";
  echo 'Updated: ' . $videoEntry->getUpdated() . "\n";
}
```